# bcrypt compare returning false when testing my login route (Express, Mongoose, jwt)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jwt, bcrypt

I'm trying to test my login route in NodeJs, Express, Mongoose, etc. My register route is working but the login route is returning the error message. My code is as follows

user schema

```
//1. require mongoose
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
//2. create schema
const User=new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    lastName:{
        type:String,
        required:false,
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    username:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    likedSongs:{//will be changed to array later
        type:String,
        default:'',
    },
    likedPlaylists:{
        type:String,
        default:''
    },
    subscribedArtists:{
        type:String,
        default:'',
    }
})
//export schema
module.exports=mongoose.model("User",User)
```

auth routes to register and login (these routes are imported into my index.js file not shown below)

```
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()
const User=require('../models/User')
const bcrypt=require('bcrypt')
const {getToken}=require('../utils/helpers')
const passport=require('passport')

router.post('/register', async (req,res)=>{
    //This code is run when /register is called to post a new user
    //req.body will be json in the form firstname, lastname, email, username
    const {firstName, lastName, email, username, password}=req.body
    //Does a user with this email already exist? yes>error
    const user= await User.findOne({email}) //email in User schema is equal to req.body email
    if (user) { //user true should make an error
        //status code by default is 200 but we want to make an error
        return res
            .status(403)
            .json({error: 'A user with this email address already exists'})
    } else{//the user does not exist so create a new user
        //do not store password in plain text, convert to a hash (not brown)
        const hashedPw=bcrypt.hash(password,10)
        const newUserData={firstName, lastName, email, username, password: hashedPw}
        const newUser=await User.create(newUserData)
        //create token to return to the user
        const token= await getToken(email,newUser)
        //return result to user
        const userToReturn={...newUser.toJSON(),token}
        delete userToReturn.password
        return res.status(200).json(userToReturn)
    }
})

router.post('/login', async (req,res)=>{
    //Get email & pw from user from req.body
    const {username,password}=req.body
    // //Check if user with given email exists if not credentials are invalid
    const user= await User.findOne({username})
    if (!user) {
        res.status(401).json({error:'your credentials are invalid'})
    }
    try {
        await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    success:false,
                    message:'Authentication Failed'
                })
            } 
            if(result) {
                const token = getToken(user)
                const loggedInUser={
                    token,
                    username:user.username
                }
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success:true,
                    message:'Login Successful! Redirecting...',
                    loggedInUser
                })
            }
            return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "Authentication Failed" })
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "Authentication Failed" });
    }
```

getToken function

```
const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken')
require('dotenv').config()

exports={}

exports.getToken= async user=>{
    const token=jwt.sign(
        {identifier:user._id},
        process.env.JWT_SECRET)
    return token
}

module.exports=exports
```

I tested line by line and I found that the user.password is returning an empty object. I realized that my user schema didn't include a password field so I tried to add that in but then the register route stopped working.

Comment: Add ```password``` field to your schema then provider your stack trace as more information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly identified that you need a `password` property in your schema so keep it. The `bcrypt.hash()` function creates a 60 character length string so if you want to implement a `minLength` or `maxLength` built in validator for your passwords then this needs to be done before you hash the password. That is achievable using `pre('save')` [hooks](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre).

As per the bcrypt [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)

> We recommend using async API if you use bcrypt on a server. Bcrypt hashing is CPU intensive which will cause the sync APIs to block the event loop and prevent your application from servicing any inbound requests or events. The async version uses a thread pool which does not block the main event loop.

Since your `router.post('/register')` callback function is marked as `async` change your hashing to:

```
const hashedPw = await bcrypt.hash(password,10)
```

Your token is not being created properly. Inside your `/register` route you are passing `email` and `newUser` to the `getToken` function. But your `getToken` function only takes one parameter (`user`) and by the looks of it you seem to be passing `email` as the parameter as `newUser` will be ignored:

```
const token= await getToken(email,newUser) //< Two parameters

exports.getToken= async user=>{ //< One parameter
    const token=jwt.sign(
        {identifier:user._id}, //< There is no user here so user._id will be undefined
        process.env.JWT_SECRET)
    return token
}
```

Inside your `/login` route you may also want to consider using `async/await` for your `bcrypt.compare` as you seem to have a mixture callbacks and `await` going on there. A much cleaner flow control would be better and there really is no need to use callbacks in your code given your `/login` function is also marked as `async`. It would look something like this:

```js
try {
    if(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)){
        const token = await getToken(user); //< You need to use await here too
        const loggedInUser={
            token,
            username:user.username
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            success:true,
            message:'Login Successful! Redirecting...',
            loggedInUser
        });
    } else {
        return res.status(401).json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Authentication Failed'
        });
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "Authentication Failed" });
}
```